# Correct way of selecting text with QTextCursor (performance issue)

Tags: pyqt6

I am trying to replace dates at the start of each block of my document, and I have a currently working PoC, but it feels sluggish. I think the problem is that I am using search when I know that the text to be replaced is in the beginning of the block, but I can't work out how I can select it.

```py
from PyQt6 import QtWidgets, QtGui
import time


class MainWindow(QtWidgets.QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()

        # Create a plain text edit widget and add some text to it
        self.text_edit = QtWidgets.QPlainTextEdit()
        text = ''
        for i in range(10000):
            text+="2022 something or the other\n2022 some other test\n"
        self.text_edit.setPlainText(text)
        self.setCentralWidget(self.text_edit)

        # Create a button and connect its clicked signal to the select_text function
        self.button = QtWidgets.QPushButton("Change Text")
        self.button.clicked.connect(self.select_text)
        toolbar = self.addToolBar("Toolbar")
        toolbar.addWidget(self.button)

    def select_text(self):
        old = ["2022"] * 20000
        new = ["2023"] * 20000
        start_time = time.perf_counter()
        cursor = self.text_edit.textCursor()
        cursor.beginEditBlock()

        for i in range(self.text_edit.document().blockCount()):
            block = self.text_edit.document().findBlockByNumber(i)
            # Search for a specific string within the block
            block_cursor = QtGui.QTextCursor(block)
            # Get a QTextCursor object for the block
            while not block_cursor.atEnd() and block_cursor.block() == block:
                # block_cursor.movePosition(QtGui.QTextCursor.Right, QtGui.QTextCursor.KeepAnchor, 4)
                block_cursor = block.document().find(old[i], block_cursor)


                if not block_cursor.isNull():
                    block_cursor.insertText(new[i])
        cursor.endEditBlock()
        end_time = time.perf_counter()
        elapsed_time = end_time - start_time
        print(f"Elapsed time: {elapsed_time:.2f} seconds")





if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication([])
    window = MainWindow()
    window.show()
    app.exec()
```

This is my current code, working as required, but I hope that selecting with move position instead of searching will speed it up.

Edit:
Based on musicamante's answer, the improved code:

```py
    def select_text(self):
        old = ["2022"] * 20000
        new = ["2023"] * 20000
        start_time = time.perf_counter()
        cursor = self.text_edit.textCursor()
        cursor.beginEditBlock()
        i=0
        doc = self.text_edit.document()
        find_cursor = QtGui.QTextCursor(doc.begin())
        while True:
            find_cursor = doc.find(old[i], find_cursor)
            if not find_cursor.isNull():
                find_cursor.insertText(new[i])
                i=i+1
                if i == 20000:
                    break
            else:
                break
        cursor.endEditBlock()
        end_time = time.perf_counter()
        elapsed_time = end_time - start_time
        print("Elapsed time: {:.2f} seconds".format(elapsed_time))
```

---

Edit2:
The goal of the application is that I have timestamps with unknown time zone settings, and instead of asking for the time zone, I have added a possible UTC offset to shift the time to UTC (when \ if needed).
I have reworked the example and the approach:

```py
from PyQt6 import QtWidgets, QtGui
import time
import datetime


class MainWindow(QtWidgets.QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()

        # Create a plain text edit widget and add some text to it
        self.text_edit = QtWidgets.QPlainTextEdit()
        text = "2022-08-02T15:41:05.000  something or the other\n2022-08-02T15:41:06.000  Some parts may contain timestamps 2021-08-02T15:42:06.000 or\u2028New lines within a block\n2022-08-02T15:42:06.000  some other test"
        self.text_edit.setPlainText(text)
        self.setCentralWidget(self.text_edit)


        # Create a button and connect its clicked signal to the select_text function
        self.button = QtWidgets.QPushButton("Change Text")
        self.button.clicked.connect(self.shift_timezone)
        toolbar = self.addToolBar("Toolbar")
        toolbar.addWidget(self.button)

    def shift_timezone(self):
        text_timestamps = [1659447665, 1659447666, 1659447726]
        start_time = time.perf_counter()
        cursor = self.text_edit.textCursor()
        cursor.movePosition(cursor.MoveOperation.Start, cursor.MoveMode.MoveAnchor)
        cursor.beginEditBlock()
        i=0
        while i<self.text_edit.document().blockCount():
            dt = datetime.datetime.fromtimestamp(text_timestamps[i]+3600)
            iso_string = dt.strftime('%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S.%f')[:-3] + 'Z'
            cursor.movePosition(cursor.MoveOperation.Right, cursor.MoveMode.KeepAnchor, 24)
            cursor.insertText(iso_string)
            cursor.movePosition(cursor.MoveOperation.NextBlock, cursor.MoveMode.MoveAnchor)
            i= i+1
        cursor.endEditBlock()
        end_time = time.perf_counter()
        elapsed_time = end_time - start_time
        print(f"Elapsed time: {elapsed_time:.2f} seconds")





if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication([])
    window = MainWindow()
    window.show()
    app.exec()
```

*(I intentionally added a space as a placeholder for Zulu in the original display text to account for multiple runs of the function)*

This works perfectly on a functional level, but the performance is atrocious (7x the runtime of just dropping the document, and creating a new one with the updated timestamps).
As I do not have control of the content, it can contain the exact same timestamps that I have, and it can also have line breaks within the block.

What I do know that all blocks will start with the timestamp, I can control the format of the timestamp, and I have the source with timestamp and the content in a different variable, making it possible to drop everything.

Am I making some obviously performance intensive mistake here?

Comment: Are you absolutely sure that the year will **always** be at the beginning of each block? Also, your update is not clear, what is the sense of searching through a list of identical items? Maybe you actually have a *dictionary* of substitutions? And what if a substitution becomes a match for a further substitution? For example, if you want to substitute every 2021 with 2022 and every 2022 with 2023?

Comment: I am 100% certain. The start of the block is a timestamp that I can manipulate, this is what the repeating list represents
After working a bit more on the issue, I have realized that the original timestamp can be in all kinds of formats, therefore before passing it to QDocument I have standardized to 2023-04-01T22:21:05.002
This means that the search is not necessarily a good idea, the good solution would be to select the start of the block and go right len(2023-04-01T22:21:05.002) characters.

Comment: Sorry but your comment makes things even more confusing. The repeated list doesn't make sense since their contents are **all the same**. And now you are telling us that you actually have to deal with timestamps, but it's unclear if what you need to replace is just the year, the full timestamp, or just a portion of it (for instance, change the date but leave the time intact). We cannot help you if you provide partial information. We need a practical and conceptually valid example (a [mre]) in order to understand the *context* of the question and its problem. In any case, see my updated answer.

Comment: I have worked a bit more with the edit2 code, but it seems as good as I can get it. Is it a better approach to save the formatting of the text somehow and re-create it?

Comment: As said, see my updated answer: since you're using plain text, there's no real benefit in using the QTextDocument interface for such a complex requirement that would make multiple search and substitutions: use regular expressions and then set the final result for the contents of the widget.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Iterating through all blocks is not efficient and, besides that, using `findBlock()` is sub optimal, since QTextDocument already provides [`QTextDocument.begin()`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-6/qtextdocument.html#begin) and [`QTextBlock.next()`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-6/qtextblock.html#next).

Also, there is no point in removing text and inserting, since insertion already removes any previous selection.

Since `find(str)` automatically considers the *current* position of the given cursor, and searches through all the document (as opposed to the regex based functions), you can use a much simpler while loop:

```py
    def select_text(self):
        start_time = time.perf_counter()
        cursor = self.text_edit.textCursor()
        cursor.beginEditBlock()

        doc = self.text_edit.document()
        find_cursor = QtGui.QTextCursor(doc.begin())
        while True:
            find_cursor = doc.find("2022", find_cursor)
            if not find_cursor.isNull():
                find_cursor.insertText("2023")
            else:
                break

        cursor.endEditBlock()
        end_time = time.perf_counter()
        elapsed_time = end_time - start_time
        print("Elapsed time: {:.2f} seconds".format(elapsed_time))
```

That said, since you are using a *plain text* widget, it doesn't make a lot of sense to use the QTextDocument interface to process basic substitutions, and using regular expressions will be extremely faster, based on the simple and fast [`re.sub()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#re.sub) function.

Considering the basic case above, it would be just a matter of using a regex that matches the pattern at the beginning of the line.

You only need to convert new line characters (which in Qt become the [Unicode Paragraphj Separator](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Newline#Unicode) (`U+2029`)), so that you can use the `^` identifier for the beginning of each line:

```py
        cursor.setPosition(0)
        cursor.movePosition(cursor.End, cursor.KeepAnchor)
        text = cursor.selectedText().replace('\u2029', '\n')

        text = re.sub(r'^2022', '2023', text, flags=re.MULTILINE)
        cursor.insertText(text)
```

This can also be achieved with multiple substitutions, for example using a simple dictionary:

```py
    substitutions = {
        '2020': '2021', 
        '2022': '2023', 
    }
    for x, y in substitutions.items():
        text = re.sub(r'^{}'.format(x), y, text, flags=re.MULTILINE)
```

But, there's a catch.
What if those pairs are incompatible? Take, for instance, the following dictionary:

```py
    substitutions = {
        '2020': '2021', 
        '2022': '2023', 
        '2021': '2022', 
    }
```

Considering the insertion order introduced with Python 3.7, you will end up with all `2020` matches replaced by `2022` instead of `2021`. And if you have no direct control over the insertion order (or you use Python<3.7), you may end up with *all* entries replaced with `2023` as well.

With that in mind, a possible solution is to use temporary placeholders and then replace them with the actual substitution.

In the following example I'm using the `@` character in order to define (and later identify) the temporary placeholders: if `2020` should become `2021` and any previous `2021` should be `2022`, those will be replaced by `@2021@` and `@2022@`, respectively; in this way, any *previous* occurrence of `2021` (without the `@` characters) will *not* be confused with `@2021@`.

In the rare case a `@<match>@` is found in the original text, a further `@` character is added until no existing match exists.

```py
    placeholder = '@'
    while True:
        for k in substitutions.keys():
            if re.search(re.compile('^' + placeholder + k + placeholder), text):
                placeholder += '@'
                break # restart search from the beginning
        else:
            break # no match with placeholders, yay!

    final = {}
    for x, y in substitutions.items():
        repl = placeholder + y + placeholder
        text = re.sub(r'^{}'.format(x), repl, text, flags=re.MULTILINE)
        final[repl] = y

    for x, y in final.items():
        text = re.sub('^' + x, y, text, flags=re.MULTILINE)
```

Comment: My apologies, you have answered my question, but I did not ask the correct question. 
I have a list with the search and replacement strings (that are different for each block), that was the reason I iterated over the blocks.

Edited the example code.

Comment: I realized that your improvement regarding the loop can be added, with:
'while block.isValid():
           (same function)
            block = block.next()
            i= i+1'
It saves about ~10% runtime